# Onomatopoeia for coughing

Tags: onomatopoeia

As the title says! I am looking for an onomatopoeia for coughing, as in:

> "[sound]" he coughed violently, as if his lungs were ...etc

Alternative suggestions are also gladly accepted :_
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Cough" *is* an onomatopoeia. If you don't want to use that, you can always try using similes and metaphors in its place. You can see more about it [over here](https://archive.org/stream/oed02arch#page/1048/mode/2up). Hope it helps!